# Shared drives option "driveMembersOnly" in G-suite is not applied via API request

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I have some problem with shared drive in google drive API by using g-suite.
So, I set up on g-suite console options which one restrict sharing by link for shared drive users. That means when you create shared drive it's default parameter for option `driveMembersOnly` is true.

But when you sent API request for create shared drive with body  - `("restrictions": {"driveMembersOnly": false })` - disk creating with opportunity shared files via links, so everything work, i tested it in august 2019.

But now - it's just don't work. I think something is changed and i need fix my code, but I use "try it" section on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/create page, try to pass any parameter in  "restrictions" section  - and API just ignore this params.

So, I don't know. Maybe it's a bug? Or maybe google change console options behavior and it's overwriting this parameter for all my API requests.
Maybe some one faced with such problem?
Support of gsuite don't help with API problems.
And this is the request:

```
curl -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?requestId=123" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer TOKEN" -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{ \"restrictions\": { \"driveMembersOnly\": false }, \"name\": \"shared drive name\"}"
```

Comment: Well, I use UPDATE functionality and it's work with same body. It's kind of solution.

```curl -X PATCH 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives/{DRIVE_ID}' -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}" -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{ \"restrictions\": { \"driveMembersOnly\": false }}"```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I create a shared drive with `"driveMembersOnly": false`, the created drive has `"driveMembersOnly": false`.

Comment: @iamblichus yeah, I think problem in my settings in admin g-suite console.

Comment: Did you change any option in the console before experiencing this? And have you checked if you can reproduce this behaviour in other accounts?